# How do i display the flash banner first and then the home page details using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, flash, banner

How do i display the flash banner first and then the home page details using javascript.I need load the flash first and then display the home page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When page loads, hide page details using javascript and then when flash is finished loading

 let javascript know that, by triggering a javascript function from flash, using `ExternalInterface.call('flashReady');`

In javascript you'll have that function:

```
function flashReady()
{
    /*now display page details*/
}
```

ExternalInterface is available for AS3, but i'm not sure if it is for AS2.
Anyway AS2 has something similar for communicating with javascript.

For details see AS3 help: Communicating between ActionScript and JavaScript in a web browser.